# Не работают скомпилированные .exe файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция, exe, pyinstaller

Компилировал свой проект на Python с помощью `pyinstaller`, когда открыл .exe файл, выдало ошибку :

[image]

Пробовал скомпилировать простейший код:

```
print ("TEST")
f = input("TEST ")
print (f)
```

и в редакторе idle он заработал, но как только я его скомпилировал, он вообще перестал запускаться и не выдавал ошибки, но и не запускался.
Ошибку выдает через раз: либо он не запускаеться, либо выдает ошибку...

PS Другие exe файлы работают

Comment: покажите, как компилируете? попробуйте с ключем -F? [Using PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)

Comment: @Jack_oS Компелирую так pyinstaller -F -w SheRIK.py естественное перед этим указав директорию

Comment: это компИлируется под win или unix?

Comment: @Jack_os не понял вопрос, под фразой win вы имели ввиду windows? Если да то код для windows

Comment: даже если вы запустите "скомпилированный" файл, то вы ничего не увидете, потому что используете ключ `-w` (режим без консоли)

Comment: компелировал программу на tkinter поетому написал с -w но даже без него антивирус блокирует файл, при отключении антивируса файл выдает ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка может возникать, если антивирус блокирует запуск. Попробуйте отключить антивирус.